# How to end cygwin offline installation down to full?

Tags: gcc, installation, cygwin, offline

I installed cygwin via offline installation and after that have got cygwin but not in full concept, - I don't even have gcc after installing and also when I do install, again above already installed, I check gcc but still havn't got any changes after

Please help!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say what the main reason what first cause that problem is the absence of internet connection

Comment: What does "in full concept" mean? How did you do your "offline installation"? Did you download all packages which you need?

Comment: I suggest that installation of setup-x86_64.exe has to provide full concept, but in my case  I can't get it without absence of internet connection

Comment: While I still don't know what a "full concept" would be, I think I understand your goal: You want to download the packages, put them i.e. on a USB stick, and install them on a PC which does not have internet access. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946382/is-it-possible-to-put-cygwin-on-a-dvd-for-an-offline-install) for a discussion of the problem.